# Creating a column from an entry in a table

Tags: sql, google-analytics, pattern-matching, vertica, web-analytics

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to take an entry in a column

`event_name where match_id = 1`

and applying that entry to every record in a new column partitioned by `visit_id` and `pattern_id`

Here's what I have:

```
| Visit_ID           | event_label  | product_list_name | event_name | match_id | pattern_id | SKU    |
|--------------------|--------------|-------------------|------------|----------|------------|--------|
| 154892456600012589 | California   | banner-101-s      | Search     | 1        | 1          | (null) |
| 154892456600012589 | sendData     | banner-101-s      | Impression | 2        | 1          | 10572  |
| 154892456600012589 | sendData     | banner-101-s      | Impression | 3        | 1          | 10573  |
| 154892456600012589 | sendData     | banner-101-s      | Impression | 4        | 1          | 10574  |
| 154892456600012589 | sendData     | banner-101-s      | Impression | 5        | 1          | 47589  |
| 154892456600012589 | sendData     | banner-101-s      | Impression | 6        | 1          | 84756  |
| 256493157982168884 | Nevada       | banner-109-s      | Search     | 1        | 2          | (null) |
| 256493157982168884 | sendData     | banner-109-s      | Impression | 2        | 2          | 58798  |
| 256493157982168884 | sendData     | banner-109-s      | Impression | 3        | 2          | 58799  |
| 256493157982168884 | sendData     | banner-109-s      | Impression | 4        | 2          | 10546  |
| 256493157982168884 | banner-109-s | banner-109-s      | Click      | 5        | 2          | 58798  |
```

I'm trying to get the following:

```
| Search     | Product_List_Name | SKU   | Impressions | Clicks |
|------------|-------------------|-------|-------------|--------|
| California | banner-101-s      | 10572 | 1           | 0      |
| California | banner-101-s      | 10573 | 1           | 0      |
| California | banner-101-s      | 10574 | 1           | 0      |
| California | banner-101-s      | 47589 | 1           | 0      |
| California | banner-101-s      | 84756 | 1           | 0      |
| Nevada     | banner-109-s      | 58798 | 1           | 1      |
| Nevada     | banner-109-s      | 58799 | 1           | 0      |
| Nevada     | banner-109-s      | 10546 | 1           | 0      |
```

Apologies if I haven't explained well! Thank you for any insights.

Comment: Is this based on a RDBMS like SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Yes, this is in vertica

Comment: Also, there must be some error in your sample data. All `Nevada` records have `match_id = 1`. Is this correct?

Comment: Does it support ANSI-SQL?

Comment: Woops, sorry about that--that's definitely not correct. I'll fix it now. It does support ANSI-SQL, to my knowledge. But I'm definitely more of an end user.

Comment: Your question is close to indecipherable.  You claim you want to filter on `match_id = 1` but your data seems to be everything else.  You mention something called a `visit_id`, but there is no such thing in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be close to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT t2.event_label AS Search, t1.product_list_name, t1.SKU,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.event_name = 'Impression' THEN 1 END) AS Impression,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.event_name = 'Click' THEN 1 END) AS Click
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.Visit_ID = t2.Visit_ID AND t2.match_id = 1
WHERE t1.match_id > 1
GROUP BY t1.Visit_ID, t1.SKU, t2.event_label, t1.product_list_name
```

The query picks all records with `match_id <> 1` matching each one of them with the corresponding `match_id = 1` record. It uses *conditional aggregation* to count the number of `Impressions` and `Clicks` per `Visit_ID` and `SKU`.

Comment: That's awesome--thank you so much! I had to add `t1.pattern_id = t2.pattern_id` to the inner join condition to limit the search term to the correct product list name, and it works beautifully. Many thanks!!

Comment: @BiancaRodriguez I'm really glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your results seem to come from a query like this:

```
SELECT event_label as Search, product_list_name, SKU,
       SUM( (event_name = 'Impression')::int ) AS Impressions,
       SUM( (event_name = 'Click')::int ) AS Clicks
FROM t
WHERE SKU IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY vent_label, product_list_name, SKU;
```

You may want to include `pattern_id` in the `GROUP BY`, but it is not in the result set, so I'm not sure.